# Geshi syntax highlighting for the R programming language

Tags: r, mediawiki, geshi

Does Geshi support the [R programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29)?

[This table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi#Supported_languages) (Geshi for MediaWiki) does not list R, so I guess the answer is no, but I just wanted to check. Is there any programming language with a similar sintax that could help highlight, at least partially, the syntax of an R script/function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

`rsplus` was removed from the table linked to by the OP on 14 April with the commit note: *Not supported by this installation*.

Not sure what that means, but Geshi has supported R in the past, though I note it is not listed on the Geshi website front page. It was added to Geshi in version 1.0.8.5 (as indicated from the `CHANGES` file (snippet thereof):

```
Version 1.0.8.5
  -  Added language files
     * AutoHotkey (Naveen Garg)
     * Awk (George Pollard)
     * GADV 4CS (Jason Curl)
     * jQuery (Rob Loach)
     * PowerBuilder (Doug Porter)
     * PureBasic (Gustavo Julio Fiorenza)
     * R / S+ (Ron Fredericks, Benilton Carvalho)
     ....
```

And there is no indication it was removed at a later date.

So it appears Geshi itself supports R, but perhaps the Mediawiki plugin doesn't yet?

---

**Original**

You did read the list fully, didn't you? ;-)

It *is* listed in the second column under the moniker `rsplus`.

Comment: @Gavin, sorry but I still don't see it. When I search for `rsplus`, I get 0 matches. Also, I don't see any entry listing R as programming language or the `rsplus` moniker. Are we looking at the same table?

Comment: @AmV, it's under `ruby` and above `sas`.

Comment: @Gavin, I tested `rsplus` and it works. I guess the table is outdated? Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't see R/S+ either.  Gavin, maybe you need to clear your browser cache?  It was included in the 4/11 revision but removed on 4/14.

Comment: @Joshua - I've never visited that page before. Why would it be in my browser cache? I know Chrome caches aggressively but...

Comment: @Joshua - wow, you're right. Is this a Chrome **feature**? If it is it is going in the bin.

Comment: @Gavin: I've never visited it either and I don't see R/S+ listed.  Weird.

Comment: Having refreshed, it disappeared.

Comment: @AmV Geshi does support R under moniker `rsplus` from version 1.0.8.5. It is not clear if you are using Geshi separately are via the Mediawiki plugin. If the former, this should work if your Geshi is reasonably up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks @Gavin. That was very helpful. I'm using Geshi mostly in MediaWiki.